# Pros and Cons of running two SQL instances to separate frontend / backend traffic (some of which is sensitive)?

Tags: node.js, angular, mariadb

I am a new developer, building a website with Node / Angular / MariaDB.  I am just now starting to use MariaDB in this project.

I understand at this point that it is best to use a backend as a middle-man between sensitive SQL data and the frontend.  However, most SQL data will not be sensitive data, i.e., nutritional information and recipes.

## Question

With these two sets of SQL data, it seems like there are two scenarios that I can pursue:

1. One MariaDB install on one server: all data, sensitive or not, passed through the backend to the frontend user.
2. Two MariaDB installs on one server: sensitive data is passed through the backend, non-sensitive data is queried directly by the frontend.

**What are the pros and cons of these two scenarios?**

**Are there other factors to take into consideration?**

**What additional information would help me evaluate which would be the best practice for my project?**

Additional questions that I think may be of interest would be whether two SQL installs present other issues (I imagine that these would need to be containerized or virtualized).

Thank you for reading, have a nice day.

Comment: Your question is soliciting an opinion, which is off topic on SO. Voting to close.

Comment: In most cases, two databases on the same instance would be deemed sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: @R.Richards, I've wondered about that sort of thing since joining StackExchange, could a sufficient answer to a question like this not just be a pros and cons list of each scenario?

Comment: @R.Richards, I apologize if this is comment spamming, but I just reworded the question in a way that I believe makes it easier to assess objectively, rather than opinion-based.  If there is anything else that you think I should change, please let me know.

Comment: Still very much about opinion. One person's pros are another person's cons. The lost of potential information you're after is very broad, which breaks another SO rule. Can you break this question down into multiple separate questions that simply ask a solution for a concern you're seeing. That way it's up to you to evaluate these different concerns and come to a weighted answer.

Comment: @jessehouwing, yeah, after more consideration it does seem that this is very opinion-based and would have to be broken down further to be more objective.  This question should probably be closed.  It seems that the best thing for me to do is to just to do backend-only SQL communication for now and decide whether to change or keep it once I understand more about how these tools work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good point to say that this might be an opinion question and should be closed.

But I think there's a single realistic approach here - to put everything behind a web service and not expose anything about the database to the frontend.

There's several reasons for this:

- At the least, you might want to have some sort of caching at some point, and that's best handled by an intermediate layer, to keep clients simpler.
- General rules about logging, identity, DDoS protection etc. should be handled at the entry to your system, rather than distributed about each component.
- AFAIK, from the browser you can only open http and web socket connections to the database, which is not sufficient to speak to a MariaDB instance, which expects to be contacted via TCP/IP with it's specific protocol.
- Security wise, having an live database accessible to anyone might open it to things like XSS attacks - people managing to insert malicious data into the database, which is then executed with the credentials of other users.

Comment: And many modern apps stick a big cache instance near the front-end to speed things up... Adding multiple layers of indirection adds overhead and maintenance costs (so does duplication of course), there is no one right answer.

Comment: This answer sounds to me like it is objectively the best thing to do, but since I do not know much about web development yet and because other users have said that this is an opinion-based question with many approaches that could be considered correct, it seems that I should not accept this answer.

Comment: @GageSorrell that's fair. Though if you reworded it as "Is it OK to expose a database service publicly on the Internet", you might get better traction.